# Why Group Session active participants not working?

Tags: ios, swift, ios15

I am using SharePlay and the Group Activities framework in my app and my usecase requires the number of participants, so I am trying to get it like this:

```
_ = SharePlayManager.sharedInstance.groupSession?.$activeParticipants.sink(receiveValue: { participants in

            print(participants.count)

        })
```

But this always prints 0, am I doing something wrong? (groupSession is 100% not nil)

Comment: When are you calling this? Are other participants joining before or after you call this?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Currently I am testing with one device and a facetime link, so it should only show 1 participant. I am calling this after the session is started and I call groupSession.join() and present custom UI